# Importing large tab-delimited .txt file into Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

I have a tab delimited .txt file that I'm trying to import into a matrix array in Python of the same format as the text file is as shown below:

123088         266         248         244         266         244         277

123425         275         244         241         289         248         231

123540         156         654         189         354         156         987

Note there are many, many more rows of the stuff above (roughly 200) that I want to pass into Python and maintain the same formatting when creating a matrix array from it.

The current code that I have for this is:

```
d = {}
with open('file name', 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
        d[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Which it slightly does what I need it to do, but not my target goal for it. I want to finish code that I can type in print(d[0,3]) and it will spit out 248.

Answer (score 36):

First, you are loading it into a dictionary, which is not going to get the list of lists that you want.

It's dead simple to use the CSV module to generate a list of lists like this:

```
import csv
with open(path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    d = list(reader)
print d[0][2] # 248
```

That would give you a list of lists of strings, so if you wanted to get numbers, you'd have to convert to int.

That said, if you have a large array (or are doing any kind of numeric calculations), you should consider using something like [NumPy](http://numpy.org) or [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). If you wanted to use NumPy, you could do

```
import numpy as np
d = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter="\t")
print d[0,2] # 248
```

As a bonus, NumPy arrays allow you to do quick vector/matrix operations. (Also, note that `d[0][2]` would work with the NumPy array too).

Comment: Is there a way to have `np.loadtxt`handle files with both numbers and text?

Comment: @CapeCode at that point I'd switch to using pandas, it will just handle it automatically. You could also use the `converters` keyword argument, but you'll end up with an object dtype array overall.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
d = []
with open(sourcefile,'rb') as source:
    for line in source:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        d.append(fields)
```

`print d[0][1]` will print 266.

`print d[0][2]` (remember your arrays are 0-based) will print 248.

To output the data in the same format as your input:

```
for line in d:
    print "\t".join(line)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great!  If I type print(d) though I end up with a very concatenated list.  How would I get the code to return a list that has defined columns like the data up top?

Comment: Can you post an example of your results and desired results?  `print(d)` or `print d` should give you the entire list of lists.  Each line from your original file will be a list of values, and each of those lists will be added to d, which is a list itself

Comment: if you'd just like to output in the same format as your original input, see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas Library:-

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv(path,delimiter="\t")
dataset.iloc[0,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to make `print(d[0,3])` output 248, but this will make `print(d[0][3])` output 248. First StackOverflow answer so IDK how show that the last two lines in my code block are actually just one long line.

```
import csv

Text_Input = r"<.txt file>"  
listoflists= []

with open(Text_Input) as txtfile:
    reader = csv.reader(txtfile)

    for row in reader:
        listoflists.append([int(row[0].split()[i]) for i in 
        range(len(row[0].split()))])
```